# How to make Siri launch app on specific keyword?

Tags: ios, swift, siri

When I say "Translate English to Spanish" Siri opens the app Google Translate.

How does Siri know to launch this app and is it possible to register your app for certain keywords with Siri?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually you can open an app telling Siri something like:

***"Open [APP NAME]"***

### My guess

In your case I guess Siri is not interpreting the sentence. When you say `Translate English to Spanish` Siri does try to understand what action should take and since no action with an hight Matching Rate is found then Siri tries to open the App having a name equals to the first word of your sentence.

### Test 1

In Italian language the app is named `Traduttore`. When I say `Traduci dall'italiano all'inglese` (Translate English to Spanish) Siri does NOT open the translator because `Traduttore` does not match `Traduci`.

### Test 2

If I say: `Musica dall'italiano all'inglese` (Music italian to english) which is not a real command, Siri does open the Music app.

### Siri and third parties apps

Right now the interaction between Siri and third parties apps is pretty limited, however maybe in the future Apple will provide the tools for a deeper interaction.

Maybe something like what is happening with HomeKit where Apple created an interface to make Siri and Home Devices to talk each other.

Comment: Grazie per la tua risposta :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should look at Siri's [custom vocabulary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/registering_custom_vocabulary_with_sirikit).

At the moment it is limited to your App's name and Apple specified [domains](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit) e.g. Workouts or Ride Booking

But if you're lucky enough that your application falls within those categories you can map some more app specific terminology.

For example, if you had a rock climbing application, *Ascent*, you could start with a voice command similar to "Hey Siri, start climb" rather than "Hey Siri, start workout with Ascent"

[image]

All of your localized vocab choices should be placed into their appropriate language-specific project directories (.lproj).