# Swift 3 - Run an app with specific keyword by using Siri

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit

According to [Intents](https://developer.apple.com/reference/intents) and thanks to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35455634/how-to-make-siri-launch-app-on-specific-keyword), I know that you can open your app via Siri with "Open [APP NAME]",

What I want to know is if it is possible to tell to Siri just only one word like 'Cheese' to open the Camera app or an other specific keyword  set beforehand to open your own app using Siri.

Is it possible ? If yes, I have to use Intents to do that or there is another way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siri runs on the OS level, so in order to use any intents you have set within your app, the user must specify your app. 
"Get a ride with Lyft" or "Message Mom in Facebook" etc..
More examples in the doc:
https://developer.apple.com/sirikit/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that to use any intents you have set within your app, the user must specify your app.

I also find this documentation with all of this key sentences... but my question is : Is there a way to run your app with only one specific keyword with Siri with or without Intents set in the app ?

I mean, in OS level, with Siri on, with no sentense like 'Message Mom in Facebook', with just only one word, for example 'Swimming' can run my app ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use shortcuts app which comes inbuilt in all iOS devices, for knowing more about Siri Shortcuts refer below links.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/adding_user_interactivity_with_siri_shortcuts_and_the_shortcuts_app

https://www.pocket-lint.com/phones/news/apple/144718-what-is-siri-shortcuts-and-how-does-it-work